# VBA - Convert multiple delimited columns into multiple row

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if someone can help me with the following,

In VBA in Excel, I have the following table :

```
Column 1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6
---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------
1.2.3.4|Apple%Car|Canada%USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|Montreal%Paris%New-York
1.3.4.6|Cat%Uniform%Dog|France|Ananas|Motel|Amsterdam%San-Diego
```

And I would like to convert this in Excel using VBA into the following table :

```
 Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5|Column 6
 :---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:|:---------:
 1.2.3.4|Apple|Canada|Tomatoes|Hotel|Montreal
 1.2.3.4|Apple|Canada|Tomatoes|Hotel|Paris
 1.2.3.4|Apple|Canada|Tomatoes|Hotel|New-York
 1.2.3.4|Apple|USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|Montreal
 1.2.3.4|Apple|USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|Paris
 1.2.3.4|Apple|USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|New-York
 1.2.3.4|Car|Canada|Tomatoes|Hotel|Montreal
 1.2.3.4|Car|Canada|Tomatoes|Hotel|Paris
 1.2.3.4|Car|Canada|Tomatoes|Hotel|New-York
 1.2.3.4|Car|USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|Montreal
 1.2.3.4|Car|USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|Paris
 1.2.3.4|Car|USA|Tomatoes|Hotel|New-York
 1.3.4.6|Cat|France|Ananas|Motel|Amsterdam
 1.3.4.6|Cat|France|Ananas|Motel|San-Diego
 1.3.4.6|Uniform|France|Ananas|Motel|Amsterdam
 1.3.4.6|Uniform|France|Ananas|Motel|San-Diego
 1.3.4.6|Dog|France|Ananas|Motel|Amsterdam
 1.3.4.6|Dog|France|Ananas|Motel|San-Diego
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes, I do have an idea on how to do this.  But SO isn't about me giving you code to do things how I think it should be done.  It's about helping you fix the code that you are writing to do the task.  Add your code attempt to the question and then we can help you get it working.

Comment: A little inspiration, use the split function. https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To get my brain going I bit. This does more or less what you want (However there is room for improvement as it currently can produce duplicate rows which it then removes at the end. I've missed something but as you haven't tried anything I haven't put any more effort in figuring out where this is happening exactly).

You'll also have to change the Ranges for where your inputs and outputs come from in the `ConvertToTable` sub. This uses a recursive function (i.e. one that calls itself) to populate your output

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ConvertToTable()
    Dim data As Variant, tmp() As Variant
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range

    With Sheet2
        data = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(2, 6)).Value2
    End With

    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        tmp = Application.Index(data, i, 0)
        arr = PopulateResults(tmp, "%", arr)
    Next i
    With Sheet4
        With .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 1)))
            .Value2 = Application.Transpose(arr)
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Function PopulateResults(tmp As Variant, delimiter As String, Results() As Variant) As Variant()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim DelCount As Long, MaxDel As Long
    Dim tmp2 As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(Results, 2) + 1
    If i = 0 Then i = 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Preserve Results(1 To UBound(tmp), 1 To i)
    For j = 1 To UBound(tmp)
        Results(j, i) = tmp(j)
        If InStr(1, tmp(j), delimiter, vbTextCompare) Then
            DelCount = 0
            Results(j, i) = Split(tmp(j), delimiter)(DelCount)
            Do
                DelCount = DelCount + 1
                tmp2 = tmp
                tmp2(j) = Split(tmp(j), delimiter)(DelCount)
                Results = PopulateResults(tmp2, delimiter, Results)
            Loop Until DelCount = Len(tmp(j)) - Len(Replace(tmp(j), delimiter, vbNullString))
        End If
    Next j
    PopulateResults = Results
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, It is much appreciated.  Sorry for the delay, I didn't get any e-mail notification for the response.

I played with the source code and I have the following, it works for all the column that contain short value.. :

```
'Transform the data
Dim data As Variant, tmp() As Variant
Dim arr() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim c As Range

    With Aggregation_Source
        data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 8)).Value2
    End With

    For i = LBound(data, 1) To UBound(data, 1)
        tmp = Application.Index(data, i, 0)
        arr = PopulateResults(tmp, "%", arr)
    Next i

With Aggregation_Source
        With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(arr, 2), UBound(arr, 1)))
            .Value2 = Application.Transpose(arr)
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Public Function PopulateResults(tmp As Variant, delimiter As String, Results() As String) As String()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim DelCount As Long, MaxDel As Long
    Dim tmp2 As Variant

    On Error Resume Next
    i = UBound(Results, 2) + 1
    If i = 0 Then i = 1
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim Preserve Results(1 To UBound(tmp), 1 To i)
    For j = 1 To UBound(tmp)
        Results(j, i) = tmp(j)
        If InStr(1, tmp(j), delimiter, vbTextCompare) Then
            DelCount = 0
            Results(j, i) = Split(tmp(j), delimiter)(DelCount)
            Do
                DelCount = DelCount + 1
                tmp2 = tmp
                tmp2(j) = Split(tmp(j), delimiter)(DelCount)
                Results = PopulateResults(tmp2, delimiter, Results)
            Loop Until DelCount = Len(tmp(j)) - Len(Replace(tmp(j), delimiter, vbNullString))
        End If
    Next j
    PopulateResults = Results
End Function
```

Now, I think that the code crash because I have one column that contains two long text separated by % more than a 1000 characters, I will try to change the type for arr() to see if it works but I think I am missing something in the code .